# Can't resolve all parameters for MatDialogRef angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working on Angular 4 and I'm trying to setup material package, and here I'm trying to try dialog, but it doesn't work maybe because of material package I'm not sure.

This is my (dialog.components.ts):

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dialog',
    templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

    public receivedNode: any;

    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

And in my module:

```
import {MatButtonModule,MatMenuModule,MatToolbarModule,MatIconModule,MatCardModule, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';


 @NgModule({
        imports: [
            CommonModule,
            MatButtonModule,
            MatMenuModule,
            MatToolbarModule,
            MatIconModule,
            MatCardModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot(
                appRoutes,
                {enableTracing: true}
            ),
        ],
        declarations: [],
        exports: [
            MatButtonModule,
            MatMenuModule,
            MatToolbarModule,
            MatIconModule,
            MatCardModule
        ],
        entryComponents: [DialogComponent],
        providers: [MatDialogRef]
    })
    export class DialogModule {
    }
```

I got this error:
[image: Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MatDialogRef: (?, ?, ?).]

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

My call function:

```
openPopup(){
        const config = new MatDialogConfig();
        const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent> = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, config);

        dialogRef.componentInstance.receivedNode = "test";
        console.log("test");
    }
```

Comment: Plz share the code where you create your dialog. Something like `this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
            width: '150px',
            height: '100%'
        });` if not have this plz read https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: @Swoox kindly check my edit

Comment: I think cause your config is empty try: `const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent> = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);` Also your **DialogComponent** need to be added in your declarations of your **module**.

Comment: @Swoox Same error, I tried to comment the openPopup() function to make sure that the error is not related to it. I'm stuck

Comment: @Swoox: what's saved in your `config` which you're passing to `open()`? the `open()` function is expects a callback and an object `data` where you can pass data. like this: `const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, { width: '300px', height: '450px',  data: { content:'Your data or text you want to pass' } });` and in the constructor you miss: `public dialog: MatDialog` it should be: `public dialog: MatDialog, public thisDialogRef: MatDialogRef<OpenDialogueComponent>`

Comment: @k.vincent I posted a basic example of one dialog (from all my dialogs) hope that helps.

Comment: @Swoox:Sorry, my previous comment was to Yazan. My bad.

Comment: @k.vincent Well hard day of working I'm confused you with Yazan too :D.

Comment: @YazanMehrez look at the answer I gave hope it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this helps this is what I have done:

At the component:

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { DialogComponent } from './dialogs'; // component name of dialog can add multiple in here.

@Component({
    selector: 'yourComponent',
    templateUrl: './yourComponent.html'
})
export class YourComponent {

  private dialogRef: any;
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {

  openPopup(){
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent , {
                                    width: '250px',
                                    height: '25%',
                                    data: { errorcode: errorCode, errormessage: errorMessage }
                                });
                                this.dialogRef.updatePosition({ top: '3%', left: '20%' });
  }
```

In the module:

```
import { DialogComponent } from './dialogs'; // component name of dialog
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        DialogComponent 
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        MatDialogModule
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        DialogComponent 
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```

And at last, the dialog(s):

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dialog',
    templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>, 
                @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any) { } // this.data.errormessage contain error message. Not sure if need OnInit.

    ngOnInit() {
    } // I have not used this. Instead, I have put the data in HTML and click on buttons from there to interact with the component.

}
```

Comment: What was the primary fix here? I'm having trouble comparing. IT would be great if there was some clarity and succinctness of what was the critical change.

Comment: Can't understand the fix. Please elaborate yours solution

Answer (score 25):

Remove `MatDialogRef` from the list of providers.

This isn't a provider, this is a reference to an Object (it ends with `Ref`)

Answer (score 8):

You need to add it in the providers only.For me below code worked .If you have used MAT_DIALOG_DATA then you need to add this as well.

```
providers: [
{ 
provide: MatDialogRef,
useValue: []
 }, 
{ 
provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, 
useValue: [] 
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with **Angular 9** (*Can't resolve all parameters for MatDialogRef: (?, ?).*), especially when the tests were executed with *Angular Material* module.

this is my solution in the *beforeEach()* section:

***Before***:

```
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                        ...
                        ...
                    providers: [
                        { provide: MatDialogRef },
                        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA }
                    ]
            }).compileComponents();

    }));
```

***After***:

```
import { MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/dialog';

beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                    ...
                    ...
                    providers: [{
                        provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {hasBackdrop: false}
                    }]
            }).compileComponents();
```

Answer (score 0):

In app.module.ts, add useValue :{} to a provide

```
Providers:[
   {provide: MatDialogRef, useValue:{}}
]
```